# player.getCurrentTime is not a function

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

```
        var interval = setInterval(function() {
            
            if(document.readyState === 'complete') {
               
                document.querySelector('video').volume = 1;
            
                let player= document.getElementById("movie_player");
                let time = player.getCurrentTime() || 0 ;
                
                if( time >= 198){
                    localStorage.setItem('ata','Küçük bir paskalya yumurtası, 11.02.2023'); 
                    window.history.back();
                    clearInterval(interval);
                }
               
            }    
        }, 100);
```

It throws constantly player.getCurrentTime is not a function in Youtube, even though i can access it through console, I check for completion of the page too why doesn't it work?

Comment: The code seems to work when used in the console. Well I don't know if it works but player.getCurrentTime() seems to return the time at which I am on the video player at least (when I print it). How do you run your function ?

Answer (score 0):

```
video = document.getElementsByClassName('video-stream')[0];
console.log(video.currentTime);
```

Although code above this works on console too, this seems to be working with js script.